# React Native Facebook login library (react-native-fbsdk) - how to change logo?

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

Im using library react-native-fbsdk and everything is working OK.
However when user clicks on button to log in via facebook......a screen appears saying "Would you like to continue".....and this shows the react native logo (the atom).  Is there a way to show a different logo? (ideally the facebook logo)

Code below

```
      <SocialIcon
        title="Sign In With Facebook"
        button
        type="facebook"
        onPress={() => {
          _facebookSignin();
        }}
      />


_facebookSignin = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await LoginManager.logInWithPermissions([
      'public_profile',
      'email',
    ]);

    if (result.isCancelled) {
      throw 'User cancelled the login process';
    }
    const data = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

    if (!data) {
      throw 'Something went wrong obtaining access token';
    }

    const firebaseCredential = await auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(
      data.accessToken,
    );
    
    const fbUserObj = await auth().signInWithCredential(firebaseCredential);

  } catch (error) {
    if (error.code === 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential') {
      Alert.alert('Email already registered');
    } else if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
      Alert.alert('Sign in cancelled');
    } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
      Alert.alert('Sign in is already in progress');
    } else {
      Alert.alert('Issue creating account', error.message);
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this logo image into your Facebook developer app https://developers.facebook.com/

https://ibb.co/ZcBhycW